# Why EDAC sbridge: ECC is disabled. Aborting

Tags: centos, xeon, ecc

I have a server with 4 x ECC memory and I installed CentOS 7+
I got EDAC sbridge: ECC is disabled. Aborting when boot up
but if I use memtest86 test I can see my memory is ECC memory and enable, the Why I got that messages?

Comment: Are you positive your motherboard supports ECC memory?

Comment: Yes, X10DAX only support ECC, and If I do memtest86 then the ECC enabled